# Android : Calling multiple layouts in single java class

Tags: android, sqlite

**Issue**

I have a java class in which i am calling multiple layouts on basis on button clicked. The button Defined on the primary page works fine. But I am Unable to do the same with the buttons on other layout pages.

**My Code**

```
public class Aptitude extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    DBHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button btnBegin,btnnext;

    //Sub category Buttons
    Button btnaptitude5,btnaptitude4,btnaptitude3,btnaptitude2,btnaptitude1;

    String Question_ID,Title,TitleDescription,QuestionText,QuestionTemplate,QuestionImage;

    TextView tvTitle,tvInstructions,tvQuestionText;

    RadioGroup rgtemplate4images;
    ImageView img;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.aptitude);


        // these buttons are on a different layout xml file...

        btnaptitude1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude5);
        btnaptitude2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude3);
        btnaptitude3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude1);
        btnaptitude4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude2);
        btnaptitude5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaptitude4);

        btnaptitude1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnaptitude5.setOnClickListener(this);

        helper=new DBHelper(this);


        btnBegin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBeginAptitude);

        btnBegin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v==btnBegin)
        {
                setContentView(R.layout.aptitudesubcategory);





            if (v== btnaptitude1)
            {               

                getAllQuestionsAptitude("1","1");

            }








//            setContentView(R.layout.template4optionsimage);
//          tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitleTemplate4optoinsImage);
//          tvInstructions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInstructionstemplate4);
//          tvQuestionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionTextTemplate4Image);
//          
//          img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewtemplate4options);
//          
//          tvTitle.setText(Title);
//          tvInstructions.setText(TitleDescription);
//          tvQuestionText.setText(QuestionText);
//          
//          String imgName = QuestionImage; // specify here your image name fetched from db
//          String uri = "drawable/" + imgName;
//          int icon = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", getPackageName());
//          img.setImageResource(icon);








        }



    }




}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440): Process: com.cldonline.assesmenttool, PID: 13440
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cldonline.assesmenttool/com.cldonline.assesmenttool.Aptitude}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at com.cldonline.assesmenttool.Aptitude.onCreate(Aptitude.java:56)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-16 06:47:18.931: E/AndroidRuntime(13440):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Use Fragment in different 2 button..

Comment: Any example to work on like this  ?

Comment: @MD sir i am new to android I m just exploring... Kindly suggest a way to acheive this

Comment: @MD I know very well how to use Fragment .

Comment: @MD `"Check the Destro Comment. Search How to work with Fragment in Android?"` those are not my words, if you don't know OP needs (as you said), don't suggest such things

Comment: @pskink Ok sorry that's my fault.Sorry again!!!! Budy!!! Let me get out from this!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in detail i like to describe your alternate solution,

you are looking for `<include>` tag. by the help of that tag you can inflate multiple layout in single layout.

for example you have main layout says **activity_main** and two other layout says **layout1** and **layout2** than you have to use `<include>` tag for inflate **layout1** and **layout2** into **activity_main**. than in java file call  ***setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);*** and first set visibility of **layout2** as ***gone*** and on on click event set **layout2** visibility ***visible*** and **layout1** visibility as ***gone***.

i have done such a thing when i have requirement like you.

**java code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_home);

    LinearLayout introduction_page = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.introduction);
    LinearLayout manifesto = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.manifesto);
    LinearLayout become_member_page = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.become_member);
    LinearLayout contacts = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacts);

    switch (MainActivity.tab_home_content)
    {
        case 1:

            introduction_page.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            manifesto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            become_member_page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            contacts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            new Get_Introduction_Textview().execute();

            break;

        case 2:

            introduction_page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            manifesto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            become_member_page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            contacts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            new Get_Manifesto_Textview().execute();
            break;

        case 3:

            introduction_page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            manifesto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            become_member_page.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            contacts.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            break;

        case 4:

            introduction_page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            manifesto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            become_member_page.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            contacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new Get_Contact_Textview().execute();

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

**tab_home xml file**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/become_member"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/become_member" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/introduction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/introduction" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/manifesto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/manifesto" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/contacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/contacts"/>
```

Comment: Can u share a small example or alink to do so

Comment: Great let me just work it out and then will accept it as an answer

Comment: new Get_Contact_Textview().execute();

What does this line Do ? And instead of textview can we use button.

Comment: dear above code is just my required code ! you can modify as per your requirement